# Find The Common Characters 1 position at a time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 Arrays

```
Array1 = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W']
Array2 = ['A','F','U','D','E','C','G','I','J','G','K','M','L','N']
```

As you can see the 2 arrays don't have same length.

I want to compare them and one position at a time and count the total number of similar Characters

so we compare the first index of array 1 with the first index of array 2. If they match (Both A or B...) we add increment count by 1 keeping in mind that they have different length

```
Output Should Be:
total number of similar Characters: 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the minimum length of both arrays and iterate over that.

```
Array1 = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W']
Array2 = ['A','F','U','D','E','C','G','I','J','G','K','M','L','N']

counter = 0
for i in range(min(len(Array1), len(Array2))):
    if Array1[i] == Array2[i]:
        counter+=1

print(counter)
```